# All combinations of ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> Lists in JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist

I need help with a implementation of a function that gives me all combinations of `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` (not `List<List<String>>`) List in fix order.

An Example for what I need:

From:

```
List1:[1,2]
List2:[3,4]
List3:[5,6]
```

To:

```
String 1 "1,3,5"
String 2 "1,3,6"
String 3 "1,4,5"
String 4 "1,4,6"
String 5 "2,3,5"
String 6 "2,3,6"
String 7 "2,4,5"
String 8 "2,4,6"
```

All Strings in `ArrayList<String>` Object

Please help me, I have no idea how to implement it.

PS: The size of `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` is variable.

PSS: ...and the size from the ArrayList lists are variable.

Comment: What do you mean by *all combinations of `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` (not `List<List<String>>`)*?

Comment: `List<List<String>>` is always better than `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`

Comment: It's quite easy with recursion. Are you familiar?

Comment: Surely the point of this homework assignment is to learn recursion on your own.

Comment: Hint: Suppose you've already got the answer for List2 and List3 (`[3, 5], [3, 6], [4, 5], [4, 6]`). How would you combine this answer with List1 to get the answer?

Comment: @PaulBoddington: yes, but its long ago, and I have only experience with simple implementations such fibonacci etc.To your second comment: I would Combine each element with each element of list1.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko: Why?

Comment: @rmlan: this not a homework assignment...! A homework would be to implement a easy fibonacci function etc.

Comment: @DynamicBit, we have to try working on interfaces, not on concrete implementations. That helps increase a program abstraction and switch freely between implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After little changes from the old rev it works now (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and deleting to much on result):

```
void generate(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> lists,
                  ArrayList<String> result, int index) {
        if (index >= lists.size()) {
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(result));
            return;
        }
        ArrayList<String> list = lists.get(index);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            result.add(list.get(i));
            generate(lists, result, index + 1);
            result.remove(result.size() - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nikolay Tornitov  I think this is not the same to my problem because the results are single Integer values and I need the combinations in Strings :(

Comment: First: Tomitov is my name:) second : read about Stringbuffer and use append operation on it.

Comment: Thanks for assistance, but I get a "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" exception.

Is it correct that the initialize value of index is 0?

The ouput is equivalent to this:

`[[11, 21]]
Exception in thread "main" [[22]]
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1`

Comment: I edited the answer, you can try again.

Comment: Still the same error. Why is there 2 removes but only 1 add on the result?